# Get the JSF navigation display-name from the current view

Tags: jsf-2

The JSF navigation case has a display-name element. How can I look-up the value of this element from the current view - assuming the view was rendered from a navigation outcome?

e.g.

```
<navigation-case>
    <display-name>I want to get this value</display-name>
    <from-outcome>test-page</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/test.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect/>
</navigation-case>
```

I can't find much in the JSF spec about this nor anything useful in the reference implementation source code.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. The display name is purely for documentation. The [`NavigationCase` class](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationCase.html) doesn't even have a getter for this.

Apart from homegrowing a `faces-config.xml` parser (not recommended), you could put it in a resource bundle instead and get from it. This also provides better internationalization possibilities.

Comment: I figured as much after looking through some of the Mojarra code. I can understand the description element included for documentation purposes, but I can't figure why display-name is as well. It sounds like it should be "displayed" somewhere!